# # 1064 - Syntax error near 'SELECT (M_ID FROM matieres WHERE LABEL =' Anglais'))' on line 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I Want that

```
INSERT INTO utilisateurs (U_ID, NAME, SURNAME, LOGIN, PASSWORD, TYPE, M_ID) VALUES ('4', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'Formateur', SELECT(M_ID FROM matieres WHERE LABEL = 'Anglais'))
```

But it's wrong

Comment: Will the sub-query always return exactly 1 row? What do you expect to happen if it returns 0 rows, or 2 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try INSERT SELECT instead:

```
INSERT INTO utilisateurs (U_ID, NAME, SURNAME, LOGIN, PASSWORD, TYPE, M_ID)
SELECT 4, 't', 't', 't', 't', 'Formateur', M_ID 
FROM matieres 
WHERE LABEL = 'Anglais'
```

Will insert the same number of rows as the SELECT returns.

Answer (score 0):

You have unwanted parentheses after the `SELECT` keyword, that should not be there.

If the subquery always returns at least one row, I find that it's clearer to do:

```
INSERT INTO utilisateurs (U_ID, NAME, SURNAME, LOGIN, PASSWORD, TYPE, M_ID)
SELECT '4', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'Formateur', M_ID 
FROM matieres 
WHERE LABEL = 'Anglais'
```